# функция в модуле не найдена Python

Tags: python, tkinter, модули, variable

В одной директории у меня располагаются основной файл Edit.py и модуль с названием control.py.
Edit.py - это Tkinter приложение, в него я импортировал модуль control.py `import control`. В этом модуле находятся функции которые работают переменными из Edit.py.

В коде моего Edit.py я делаю бинд клавиш, вызывающих определенные функции из модуля.

```
root.bind("<Control-KeyPress-o>", control.main(open()))
```

В control.py я добавил функцию main в которой находиться функция open, которую я попробовал вызвать, но у меня в терминале вышла ошибка говорящая что функция open не найдена:

```
  File "Edit.py", line 558, in <module>
    window.bind("<Control-KeyPress-o>", control.main(open()))
NameError: name 'open' is not defined
```

Вот содержание моего модуля

```
def main(*args):
    def open():
        with open('./local/session.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            SessionJson = json.load(f)

        class_file.file_open = askopenfilename(defaultextension=".txt", filetypes=[("All Files", "*.*")])

        if class_file.file_open is not None and class_file.file_open != '':
            window.title(os.path.basename(class_file.file_open) + " - Editor")

            Textedit.delete(1.0, END)
            class_file.file = open(class_file.file_open, "r")
            Textedit.insert(1.0, class_file.file.read())
            class_file.file.close()
            check_file_extension()
            # Load a last file to Json
            SessionJson['file'] = str(class_file.file_open)
            with open('./local/session.json','w') as f:
                json.dump(SessionJson ,f)
```

Под функцией open находятся другие, подобные ней.

Интересно что если добавить в Edit.py эту функцию open, то все выполниться как надо. Может это связано с тем как импортируется мой модуль.
Почему выходит  эта ошибка, и как ее можно исправить?

Comment: Функция, объявленная внутри другой функции сам по себе видна только внутри этой функции (но не видна на уровне модуля). Просто вытащите ее из функции. Вообще, лучше не называть функции и переменные так же как стандартные функции Python.

Comment: insolor, Спасибо вам за ответ. Я так и сделал, но теперь у меня возникла новая проблема - возникают ошибки из за ненайденных переменных и модулей, которые объявлены в основном фале. Например в Edit.py я импортировал модуль json, а в функции control.py происходит работа с ним, и выходит эта ошибка:
                                                `File "D:\Editor\control.py", line 4, in open_file
    SessionJson = json.load(f)
NameError: name 'json' is not defined`, в чем может быть дело?

Comment: Импортируйте json в том модуле, в котором с ним работаете. Можно конечно делать что-то вроде `from Edit import json`, но для стандартных модулей так обычно не делают.

Comment: А что делать с переменными? Или в случае с `from Edit import json` с ними не будет проблем?

Comment: Я не знаю, что у вас за переменные, и что вы хотели с ними делать, поэтому не могу ответить на ваш вопрос. "Или в случае с from Edit import json с ними не будет проблем?" - без понятия, про какие проблемы вы говорите. Но как я уже сказал, обычно так не делают, лучше импортировать json именно в том модуле, в котором с ним собираетесь работать. В импорте стандартного модуля через другой модуль нет никакого практического смысла, и это только запутывает код.

Comment: Да, я об этом не упомянул. В основном моем файле у меня есть переменная Textedit с виджетом Text, и в модуле из control.py изменяется текст внутри этого виджета, Textedit так же не находится. Импорт `from Edit import Textedit` не сработал без ошибки - `AttributeError: module 'control' has no attribute 'open_file'`, вызывал функцию я так `control.open_file()`.

Comment: Приведите код в самом вопросе. Без этого бессмысленно что-то в комментариях обсуждать.